# Default mode in GitVersion config file

Tags: gitversion

I am finding it difficult to get started with gitversion.

My question here is how to interpret the [config](https://gitversion.net/docs/configuration) file.

I have GitVersion.yml config file which looks like the following.

1. So now what would be the mode on the second line represent? Is it the default one that would be considered if mode is not specified for a branch?
2. In the following scenario all of the branches have the mode specified. So what would that mean? For any of the branches(master, release, feature, pull request, hotfix, support and develop) the respective modes specified(for ex ContinuousDeployment is specified for develop) will be considered? Will the mode setting at the branch level override the setting on line 2?
3. And finally, say I create a new branch urgentfix(not specified in the yaml config file), then ContinuousDelivery mode will be considered because its the default one?

```
next-version: 6.0.1
mode: ContinuousDelivery
branches:
  master:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^master
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  release:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: beta
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^releases?[/-]
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: true
    pre-release-weight: 1000
  feature:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: useBranchName
    increment: Inherit
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^features?[/-]
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  pull-request:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: PullRequest
    increment: Inherit
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    tag-number-pattern: '[/-](?<number>\d+)[-/]'
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^(pull|pull\-requests|pr)[/-]
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  hotfix:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: beta
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^hotfix(es)?[/-]
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  support:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^support[/-]
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  develop:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: unstable
    increment: Minor
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: true
    regex: ^dev(elop)?(ment)?$
    tracks-release-branches: true
    is-release-branch: false
ignore:
  sha: []
merge-message-formats: {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. This is the "global" versioning mode for all branches (unless overridden in a branch configuration under the `branches` section).
2. Yes, the modes specified on the individual branch configurations override the global setting on line 2.
3. In this case (and the documentation isn't 100% clear that this is what happens, but  based on my experience, I believe this to be true), since you haven't specified any `regex`es for your branch configurations, I believe that GitVersion will "fallback" to the defaults. The regex for feature branches is `^features?[/-]`. Basically, a branch that optionally starts with `feature` (singular or plural) followed by a `/` or `-` (and not explicitly specified in the regex) followed by anything else. Since `urgentfix` does not match any of the other branch default regexes (according to GitFlow), `urgentfix` is considered a feature branch.

For number 3 above, it's unclear to me if the `branches` section is a free-form section where you can add any branch specification you want (e.g. add an `urgentfix:` section), or if you must use one of the "pre-defined" ones (which are all based on GitFlow branches).

I suppose you could try creating your own configuration section and see if that works.

If not, you might want to "hijack" one of the other branch configurations you may not be using to achieve what you desire. If you go this route, you may need to override other settings in the configuration, such as `source-branches`, in order for GitVersion to be able to properly calculate versions. And of course, don't forget to use an appropriate regex so GitFlow knows to use this configuration for `urgentfix` branches.

HTH.

**UPDATE**

I just saw in their documentation that you can add your own branch configurations apart from the ones that are well known for GitFlow or GitHubFlow. But the onus is on you to setup the configuration such that GitVersion calculates the version according to your requirements.